# How to hash strings in python(django) and compare the hashed value with a given string

Tags: python, django, encryption, hash

I'm working on a web app that allows users to sign up then login, I used the following functions to hash the password

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
import math

def encrypt_password(pswd):
    encrypt_pswd = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(pswd, rounds=(int(math.pow(len(pswd),3))), salt_size=(len(pswd)*2))
    return encrypt_pswd

def verify_password(pswd, e_pswd):
    en_pswd = encrypt_password(pswd)
    if en_pswd == e_pswd:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

my problem is that the string I hashed doesn't produce the same result when I hash it for a second time. How can I resolve this issue or what methods can I use hash the password, store in the database and compare that value with the one from the login form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [verify](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.ifc.html#passlib.ifc.PasswordHash.verify) function

```
def verify_password(pswd, e_pswd):
    return pbkdf2_sha256.verify(pswd, e_pswd)
```